# LibGDX html:superDev task giving me an error

Tags: html, web, libgdx, gwt-super-dev-mode

So I've been trying to run the libGDX command "gradlew html:superDev" for my project but it always gives me and error part way through the process:

```
> Task :html:beforeRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':html:beforeRun'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':html:grettyRunnerJetty94'.
   > Could not find org.gretty:gretty-runner-jetty94:3.0.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/C:/Users/Joachim/.m2/repository/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94/3.0.2/gretty-runner-jetty94-3.0.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

This is what the build.gradle file looks like (the one located in the project folder):

```
buildscript {
    

    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.0.13'
        classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.3'
        

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "ludum-dare-48"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.14'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.12'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.3'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
        gdxControllersVersion = '2.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"
    apply plugin: "org.gretty"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion:sources"
        
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        
    }
}
```

Any help in fixing this problem would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the [maven reposotories](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gretty/gretty-runner-jetty94) it seems that there is **no such version 3.0.2** of the project you are looking for. Maybe it got deleted and **replaced by version 3.0.3**.

So a solution would be to check your `build.gradle` file (probably the one in the html project) and replace the string `org.gretty:gretty-runner-jetty94:3.0.2` by either `org.gretty:gretty-runner-jetty94:3.0.3` or `org.gretty:gretty-runner-jetty94:2.3.0`.

You should try version 3.0.3 first, since 2.3.0 might be lacking some features.

Comment: This doesn't work. I assume this is so because it isn't looking in the wright URLs. It lists what URLs it searched.

Comment: Maybe it's because [JCenter is shutting down](https://libgdx.com/news/2021/04/gdx-1-10#jcenter-is-shutting-down) and is replaced by `gradlePluginPortal()` in the new libGdx version. If this also doesn't work it would be helpfull if you added you `build.gradle` file to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I went to my main gradle.build file and in the repositories {} block for both the buildscript {} block and the allprojects {} block I put `gradlePluginPortal()` and now the superDev command works fine.